# cURL call to Twitter API meeting "Rate Limit" without making more than 5 requests

Tags: php, twitter, curl

I'm just starting to mess around with a very, very basic call to the
Twitter API (http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json) to
pull my tweets to my website through cURL. However, using a page that
nobody knows exists yet (thus eliminating the possibility of
inadvertent traffic), I'm getting a Rate Limit Exceeded thing before
I've had the chance to even test it. It says it resets at 5 past the
hour, so I check again, and for a minute it works but then it's back
to telling me my rate limit is exceeded. A few questions for anyone who knows about the Twitter API and/or cURL:

First, is the rate limit applied to my server (instead of the user)? I would assume so, but
that could make it tough of course. Even one API call per visitor
could, on a site with marginal traffic, easily surpass the rate limit
in an hour. Is there a way to associate the call with the visitor, not
the server? Seems like probably not, but I'm not entirely sure how the
whole API works, and cURL does seem to be advocated in a number of
places. I'm aware that if I use JSON and AJAX the data in I can make
that request from the user, but just for the sake of argument, what
about cURL?

Second, any idea how I could be surpassing my rate limit without even
refreshing the page? I pay for hosting at another location, so I might
be sharing server space with another site, but my site definitely has
a unique IP, so that should … that should be OK, right? So how is it
that I'm surpassing the rate limit without even running the code (or
by running it once?)?

Here's what I've got for code, if it helps:

```
$ch=curl_init("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=screenname");
    curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>5,
        )
    );
$temp=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$results=json_decode($temp,true);
```

Also, I've now got it so that if Twitter returns a Rate Limit error, it records the error in a text file, as well as the time that the limit will reset. Looking at that file, the only time it updates (I don't have it rewrite, it just adds on) is when I've loaded the page (which is maybe once or twice in an hour), so it's not like something else is using this page and calling on this URL.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authenticated requests should count against the user's 350/hour limit. Non-authenticated requests get counted against your IP address's 150/hour limit.

If you're running into the limits during development, Twitter has generally been quite willing to whitelist dev server IPs.

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting

> Some applications find that the default limit proves insufficient. Under such circumstances, we offer whitelisting. It is possible to whitelist both user accounts and IP addresses. Each whitelisted entity, whether an account or IP address, is allowed 20,000 requests per hour. If you are developing an application and would like to be considered for whitelisting you fill out the [whitelisting request form](http://twitter.com/help/request_whitelisting). Due to the volume of requests, we cannot respond to them all. If your request has been approved, you'll receive an email.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I'm only pulling my own Twitter stream, so there's not going to be any need to get any other usernames involved, or even my own since it's a public stream.

Comment: I always forget that I can't have returns in these replies. Any idea why I might be running into the rate limit, though? I'm not refreshing the page anywhere close to 150 times. I shouldn't need whitelisting because it should be four lines of code and I'm set. But for some reason within 20 minutes of the reset, even if I haven't loaded the page once, my limit is reached.

Comment: I'd check what third-party apps you're connected with at http://twitter.com/settings/connections. You're not on an IP shared with a bunch of other folks, I assume?

Comment: But I'm not logging in, so it shouldn't matter what apps I'm connected to should it? I don't think I'm sharing an IP with other folks, but it is possible. I'm trying to figure that out.